# Cypress tests executed via Azure pipeline don't have access to internally hosted test website

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress

I have a set of automated Cypress tests. Some of the tests are executed on internal websites (Not reachable from outside the network) and some are executed on public website. These tests can be executed successfully by running the test from an internal machine.

Problem: Now I try to set up a pipeline in Azure DevOps to trigger the tests.
Only tests on the public website can be executed successfully.
The tests for our internal website fail because the website can't be found.
So, somehow I need to make sure that the machine on which the tests are executed in DevOps, has acecss to our network. Or maybe, there is any other solution.
Can someone maybe help?

My pipeline yaml looks like this. It triggers the test on ubuntu latest.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

  - task: Yarn@3
    displayName: yarn install
    inputs:
      projectDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/UIAutomation'
      arguments: install

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Run Cypress Tests'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/UIAutomation'
      script: yarn cypress run --browser chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I already know. I need a self-hosted agent which is registered in an agent pool in devops and which has internal access.